# Asp.NET and Cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, web-config, session-cookies, sessionid

In my website I am not using cookies. When the user logs in, I validate the user credentials by getting password from database and if user credentials are validated I store the Email ID and other user related information into a session. I use the session values in other pages to validate the user for that page.

WebConfig:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".YAFNET_Authentication" loginUrl="Home.aspx" 
protection="All" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseUri"/>
    </authentication>
```

If I select UseUri for cookiless then the url is

```
(S(2zlu5ry2ewsqfuzkfcmy1xl5))/Home.aspx
```

What is attached to my url, Is it secure to expose this value, I want to use cookie-less session because most of the iPhones browsing the site have cookies disabled.

I have an SSL certificate for my website. I am worried if displaying the above value in url will compromise the security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default session id values are stored in cookies. If you mention cookieless mode,session id will be appended to the URL.

**FROM MSDN**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

> Session Identifiers
>
> Sessions are identified by a unique identifier that can be read by
>   using the SessionID property. When session state is enabled for an
>   ASP.NET application, each request for a page in the application is
>   examined for a SessionID value sent from the browser. If no SessionID
>   value is supplied, ASP.NET starts a new session and the SessionID
>   value for that session is sent to the browser with the response.
>
> By default, SessionID values are stored in a cookie. However, you can
>   also configure the application to store SessionID values in the URL
>   for a "cookieless" session.
>
> A session is considered active as long as requests continue to be made
>   with the same SessionID value. If the time between requests for a
>   particular session exceeds the specified time-out value in minutes,
>   the session is considered expired. Requests made with an expired
>   SessionID value result in a new session.
>
> **Security Note** SessionID values are sent in clear text, whether as a
>   cookie or as part of the URL. A malicious user could get access to the
>   session of another user by obtaining the SessionID value and including
>   it in requests to the server. If you are storing sensitive information
>   in session state, it is recommended that you use SSL to encrypt any
>   communication between the browser and server that includes the
>   SessionID value.